# Condition is true to start counting, until the next row is true to restart counting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

expected result table

```
    bool    count
0   FALSE   
1   FALSE   
2   TRUE    0
3   FALSE   1
4   FALSE   2
5   FALSE   3
6   TRUE    0
7   FALSE   1
8   TRUE    0
9   TRUE    0
```

How to calculate the value of column 'count'

Comment: You already have the `count` column in your dataframe? Please explain more about it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
g = df['bool'].cumsum()
df['count'] = df['bool'].groupby(g).cumcount().where(g.gt(0))
```

Alternative:

```
g = df['bool'].cumsum()
df['count'] = (df['bool'].groupby(g).cumcount()
              .where(df['bool'].cummax())
              )
```

Output:

```
    bool  count
0  False    NaN
1  False    NaN
2   True    0.0
3  False    1.0
4  False    2.0
5   True    0.0
6   True    0.0
7  False    1.0
8  False    2.0
9  False    3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
# create bool dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(bool_= [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]), dtype= bool)
df.index = list("abcdefghij")

# create a new Series unique integers to associate a group for the rows
# between True values
ix = pd.Series(range(df.shape[0])).where(df.bool_.values, np.nan).ffill().values

# if the first rows are False, they will be NaNs and shouldn't be 
# counted so only perform groupby and cumcount() for what is notna
notna = pd.notna(ix)
df["count"] = df[notna].groupby(ix[notna]).cumcount()

>>> df   
   bool_  count
a  False    NaN
b  False    NaN
c   True    0.0
d  False    1.0
e  False    2.0
f   True    0.0
g   True    0.0
h  False    1.0
i  False    2.0
j  False    3.0
```

Comment: How to make it null before the first true appears

Comment: the use of pd.notna makes sure that cumcount only counts from the first True value, since ix will have NaNs until the first True value is found. I also adjusted it slightly so it's independent of the index (that's why I demonstrated it with the index consisting of letters)

Answer (score 1):

You can try groupby the cumsum  of `bool` column then `transform` a customize function to check if first element in each group is `True`

```py
df['m'] = df['bool'].cumsum()
df['out'] = (df.groupby(df['bool'].cumsum())
             ['bool'].transform(lambda col: range(len(col)) if col.iloc[0] else [pd.NA]*len(col)))
```

```
print(df)

    bool  count  m   out
0  False    NaN  0  <NA>
1  False    NaN  0  <NA>
2   True    0.0  1     0
3  False    1.0  1     1
4  False    2.0  1     2
5  False    3.0  1     3
6   True    0.0  2     0
7  False    1.0  2     1
8   True    0.0  3     0
9   True    0.0  4     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not clear.
We need a little more context and objectives to work with here.

Let's assume that you have a dataframe of Boolean values [True, False], and you wish to compute a count of how many "True" and how many "False"

```
import pandas as pd
import random

## Randomly generating Boolean values to populate a dataframe
choices = [ 'True', 'False' ]
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(10), columns = ['boolean'])
df['boolean'] = df['boolean'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(choices))
```

**Randomly generated data**

```
  boolean
0   False
1   False
2   False
3    True
4   False
5   False
6   False
7    True
8   False
9   False
```

```
## Reporting the count of True and False values
results = df.groupby('boolean').size()
print(results)
```

**Results**

```
boolean
False    8
True     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain the count not in `pandas` way, you can try this.

```
result = []
count = np.nan
for i in df['bool']:
    if i == True:
        count = 0
        result.append(count)
    if i == False:
        count += 1
        result.append(count)
    elif i == False:
        result.append(np.nan)
        

result
Out[4]: [nan, nan, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0]

df['count'] = result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the sum of all the elements in count then you can do it this way:

```
Count_Total = df['count'].sum()
```